# Subtracting columns in a Pandas Dataframe with timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python and have inherited code that loads data according to a certain ID from a source and then adds the relevant data to columns in a DataFrame. The data is monthly data with a timestamp connected to it. I want to subtract one column in the DataFrame from another in the same DataFrame, but get error messages.

In the code, I have a `load_and_get_levels()` function that first calls a function, `make_df()`, that loads the data I need and puts it in a DataFrame. This function again calls the `load_data()` function, which I think returns a DataFrame object consisting of two columns (one datestamp column and one column with the actual data).

```
import pandas as pd

time_series_names = [
'Prod1',
'Prod2',
'Prod3',
'Prod4',
'Prod5',
'Prod6',
'Prod7',
]

def make_df(time_series_names):
    # Make a data frame with the first time series
    time_series_df = pd.DataFrame(load_data(time_series_names[0],
        start_time, end_time, time_zone))
    # Add remaining time series to the data frame.
    for ts_name_name in time_series_names[1:]:
        additional_ts = load_data(ts_name, start_time,
            end_time, time_zone)
        time_series_df = pd.merge(time_series_df,
            pd.DataFrame(additional_ts),
            left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
    return time_series_df

def load_data(ts_name, start_time, end_time, time_zone='Europe/Oslo'):
    # get_ts_range() returns time series data with a certain time range
    ts_json = get_ts_range(ts_name,
        start_time.timestamp()*1000,
        end_time.timestamp()*1000)
    ts_points = ts_json['points']
    time_series_df = pd.DataFrame(ts_points,
        index=pd.to_datetime([point[0] for point in ts_points],
        unit='ms').tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert(time_zone),
        columns=['time', 'value'])
    series = time_series_df['value']
    series.name = ts_json['name']
    return series

def levels(time_series_df):
    # Estimates Prod1 - Prod7
    ts_levels = time_series_df['Prod1'] - time_series_df['Prod7']
    return ts_levels

def load_and_get_levels():
    ts_dframe = make_df(time_series_names)
    ts_df_levels = levels(ts_dframe)
    print(ts_df_levels)
```

What I want in the end is to subtract two columns in the Data Frame created in make_df(). When I try to do this:

```
ts_levels = time_series_df['Prod1'] - time_series_df['Prod7']
```

...I get a `KeyError`:

```
File "C:..../xxx.py", line 74, in levels
    ts_levels = time_series_df['Prod1'] - time_series_df['Prod7']

  File
"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
line 2927, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File
"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py",
line 2659, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in
pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in
pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'Prod1'
```

Why doesn't it work to subtract two columns by using the names of them?

Comment: What do you get if you call `print(time_series_df.columns)`?

Comment: @LaurensKoppenol I then get Index(['time', 'value'], dtype='object')

Comment: The error means column `Prod1` is not in your dataframe. And neither is `Prod7`.

Comment: But why is it not?

Comment: Can you put a `print(series.name)` after `series.name = ts_json['name']` in `load_data`? I suspect it will print the same value 8 times.

Comment: series.name:  prod1
series.name:  prod2
series.name:  prod3
series.name:  prod4
series.name:  prod5
series.name:  prod6
series.name:  prod7

Comment: These are lowercase letters.. Does this has anyhing to say? I guess?

Comment: It worked now, when I changed to ts_levels = time_series_df['prod1'] - time_series_df['prod7']. Don't see where in the code the uppercase letters are transformed to lowercase, but it works now. :) Thanks!

Comment: not `time_series_names` is used but rather the name returned from `get_ts_range`, which is probably lowercase. I do not understand why your first print statement does not list any columns names though. Good luck!